# Spring Integration DSL Syntax problem - how to dynamically construct subflows?

Tags: java, lambda, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to construct a complex flow in Spring Integration where the sub flows are dynamically defined at runtime. Code that functions perfectly well in the master flow definition fails the compile in the sub flow definition. Since the construct *appears* identical, it is not obvious what is going on. Any explanation would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

The master flow definition is coded something like this:

```
        StandardIntegrationFlow flow = IntegrationFlows
            .from(setupAdapter,
                    c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(1000L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).maxMessagesPerPoll(1)))

// This one compiles fine
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("start", "start\")")
                    .headerExpression("end", "payload[0].get(\"end\")"))

            .split(tableSplitter)
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("object", "payload[0].get(\"object\")"))
            .channel(c -> c.executor(stepTaskExecutor))
            .routeToRecipients(r -> this.buildRecipientListRouterSpecForRules(r, rules))
            .aggregate()
            .handle(cleanupAdapter).get();
```

buildRecipientListRouterSpecForRules is defined as:

```
    private RecipientListRouterSpec buildRecipientListRouterSpecForRules(RecipientListRouterSpec recipientListSpec,
        Collection<RuleMetadata> rules) {
    rules.forEach(
            rule -> recipientListSpec.recipientFlow(getFilterExpression(rule), f -> createFlowDefForRule(f, rule)));

    return recipientListSpec;
}
```

createFlowDefForRule() is just a `switch()` wrapper to choose which actual DSL to run for the flow defined by the rule.  Here is a sample

```
    public IntegrationFlowDefinition constructASpecificFlowDef(IntegrationFlowDefinition flowDef, RuleMetadata rule) {

    return flowDef
       // This enrichHeaders element fails to compile,
       // The method headerExpression(String, String) is undefined for the type Object
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("ALC_operation", "payload[0].get(\"ALC_operation\")"));

 }
```

Comment: `>fails the compile` - exactly what "fails to compile", and with what error(s)?

Comment: The .enrichHeaders element chokes, with "headerExpression(String, String) is undefined for the type Object". It looks to me like the java language somehow makes the type ambiguous and the  HeaderExpressionSpec is not being seen as a viable data type in the lambda (wild guess)

Comment: Edited question and code sample to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's better to put such explanations in the question text, rather than as comments in the code snippets; I completely missed that comment.

Can you provide a stripped-down (simpler) example (complete class) that exhibits this behavior so we can play with it?

I tried to simplify what you are doing, and this compiles fine and works as expected:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So65010958Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So65010958Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("foo")
                .routeToRecipients(r -> r.recipientFlow("true", f -> buildFlow(f)))
                .get();
    }

    private IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> buildFlow(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> f) {
        return f.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression("foo", "'bar'"))
                .channel(MessageChannels.queue("bar"));
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel foo, PollableChannel bar) {
        return args -> {
            foo.send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));
            System.out.println(bar.receive(0));
        };
    }

}
```

> GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={foo=bar, id=d526b8fb-c6f8-7731-b1ad-e68e326fcc00, timestamp=1606333567749}]

So, I must be missing something.

Comment: The answer is that the method signature must use IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> f , not IntegrationFlowDefinition f. Without the placeholder for the type, Java doesn't know what to do here.